# Flash Message Customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, flash-message

In my **application.rb**:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
<% end %>
```

which works for me because I have about 10 different flash lines of code, but on only one of them I want the flash to display as red

```
flash[:danger] = 'Striked added' # MAKE RED
```

Do you know a quick fix?

Comment: have you registered this flash message type in `ApplicationController`? `add_flash_types :danger`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string interpolation in the `:class` option with a conditional statement to add another class for only a certain kind of flash:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info #{'red' if name == :danger}") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I replaced your flash code with mine, but then when the flash popped up `flash[:danger] = 'Striked added'` it still showed as an `alert-info` instead of as danger

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "I replaced your flash code with mine." What did you end up with in the `:class` option?

Comment: This is the html output: `<div class="alert alert-info ">Striked added</div>`

Comment: Can you share the value of your `:class` option in the ruby code?

Comment: Sorry now I'm confused. `:class` option? I copy and pasted your code so the class is `"alert alert-info #{'red' if name == :danger}"`

Comment: ah. are you sure `:danger` is showing up as the `name` variable in that code? it sounds like the conditional `name == :danger` isn't returning `true`

Comment: Yea I'm sure. I think alert alert-info is overriding `:danger` before it can be used for the conditional or `:danger` isn't being set at all since if I take out the whole class then nothing comes up for the flash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98863/discussion-between-sixty4bit-and-anthonygalli-com).